# How to count the occurrences of single items in a list of lists in descending order?

Tags: python, list, count

```
x=[['apple', 'banana', 'carrot'],
['apple', 'banana'],
['banana', 'carrot']]
```

I want the result to look like this:

```
dict  = {'banana': 3,'apple': 2, 'carrot': 2}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "flatten" your `x`, and then just count, while iterating over unique elements of the (flat) `x`:

```
x = [['apple', 'banana', 'carrot'],
    ['apple', 'banana'],
    ['banana', 'carrot']]

flat_x = [a for b in x for a in b]
res = {a: sum(b == a for b in flat_x) for a in set(flat_x)}
print(res)
# {'carrot': 2, 'apple': 2, 'banana': 3}
```

Another way to flatten-out the list-of-lists is to use `chain` from `itertools`, so you can use:

```
from itertools import chain
flat_x = list(chain(*x))
```

Answer (score 0):

One-liner solution (if you don’t mind the import):

```python
import collections

lists = [
    ['apple', 'banana', 'carrot'],
    ['apple', 'banana'],
    ['banana', 'carrot']    
]

print(collections.Counter(
    item for sublist in lists for item in sublist).most_common())
```

Documentation: [`Counter.most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common), [generator expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions).